# React-hot-loader doesn't propagate changes

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader

My problem is that react-hot-reload detect the changes and the modules that need to be update, and apparently does update the modules, but nothing in my browser changes.

Here's the version of the libraries I'm using:

- react - 16.8.3
- react-dom (patched by react-hot-loader ) - 16.8.3
- react-hot-loader - 4.8.0
- webpack - 4.29.6

Below, my webpack-dev-server config:

```
historyApiFallback: true,
hot: true,
stats: 'none',
quiet: true,
port: port,
host: host,
```

Relevant part of my webpack config

```
entry: [
  'react-hot-loader/patch',
  'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
  'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
  './src/index.js',
],
resolve : {
  alias: {
    'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom'
  }
},
```

My .babelrc:

```
"plugins": [
  "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
  "react-hot-loader/babel"
]
```

My initial component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root'

class App extends Component<PropTypes, StateTypes> {
  render (): React$Element<*> {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route
                    path="/home"
                    render={ (props: Object): React$Element<*> => <HomeView {...props } /> }
                />
                <Route component={ IntroView } />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default hot(App)
```

Lastly, my entry file:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './app'

const appContainer = document.getElementById('appContainer')

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept()
  if (appContainer) ReactDOM.render(<App />, appContainer)
} else if (appContainer) {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, appContainer)
}
```

If I do any code change that was supposed to trigger an update, that's my console:

```
[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
[WDS] App hot update...
[HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/df32ff4...hot-update.json.
[HMR] Updated modules:
[HMR] - ./src/library/protons/ModalWorkflow/sandbox/workflowStepOne.js
[HMR] - ./src/library/protons/ModalWorkflow/sandbox/index.js
[HMR] - ./src/configs/routes.js
[HRM] - ./src/views/intro/index.js
[HRM] - ./src/view/home/index.js
[HRM] - ./src/app.js
[HRM] App is up to date.
```

Browser doesn't reflect the code changes at all.
No errors, no warnings.

Tried several different approaches to check any potential mistake, but as of right now I'm in this hopeless spot, no idea what else I could try.

Comment: Same exact issue and no information anywhere. It "works" but it doesn't actually do anything 99% of the time when it updates and tells me it's up to date.

Comment: I've never been able to make react-hot-loader v4 work properly. Every 6 months or so, I make an attempt but I have the same kind of problems mentioned here. So far I'm staying with v3 and it works how it should. My comment of today comes from a warning that React will remove lifecycle methods needed for v3 AppContainer, 'componentWillReceiveProps' and so v3 will stop working if not patched.